# How to prevent 'Unknown column' error with rails has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

Attempting to refactor a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association in rails 4 in order to add extra columns but am struggling over a self-referential `has_many_through`.

An item can consist of many components. Components are really just Items and can therefore have components of their own;

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :components, through: :component_items
  has_many :component_items
end

class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, through: :component_items
  has_many :component_items
  self.table_name ="Items"
end

class ComponentItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  has_many :components
end
```

And the schema looks like...

```
create_table "component_items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "item_id",      limit: 4, null: false
  t.integer "component_id", limit: 4, null: false
end

create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "sku",    limit: 255
  t.decimal  "height", precision: 6, scale: 2
  t.decimal  "width",  precision: 6, scale: 2
  t.decimal  "depth",  precision: 6, scale: 2
end
```

Then

```
i=Item.first
i.components
```

I get:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'items.component_item_id' in 'on clause': SELECT `items`.* FROM `items` INNER JOIN `component_items` ON `items`.`component_item_id` = `component_items`.`id` WHERE `component_items`.`item_id` = 87675

I don't need a column `'items.component_item_id'`, so where have I mistakenly defined it? Then, how do I get this association to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is appeared because rails searches for column `component_item_id` in table `items`, but you have no such column, I believe you should create the `belongs_to` relation in `item` to it, **BUT** it seems you have just wrong realtions between schema and models, so for the current scheme you defined I propose models:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :components, through: :component_items
  has_many :component_items
end

class Component < Item
  has_many :items, through: :component_items
  has_many :component_items
end

class ComponentItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :component
end
```

**NOTE** this requires an additional string field named `type` in `items` table.

Comment: The error states it is looking for the column on the `items` table, not `component_items`. Renaming the column will not fix the issue. Specifying a foreign key does not change anything.

Comment: Why the need for `type`?